# Match specific words in a string and categorize them

Tags: php

I'm pretty new to PHP so bear with me here.  I'm trying to iterate through the words in a string of text, look for specific words, categorize them, and then count the number of times each word category was hit.  I was able to do the easy part but I'm having problems counting the number of times each category is matched.  Here's the main function that accepts my string:

```
public function matchThemeTest($query){
    $marriageNum = 0;
    $criminalNum = 0;
    $contactNum = 0;
    $keywords = array(
        'background'=> array('category'=>'criminal'),
        'marriage'  => array('category'=>'marriage'), 
        'criminal'  => array('category'=>'criminal'),
        'arrest'    => array('category'=>'criminal'),
        'divorce'   => array('category'=>'marriage'),
        'person'    => array('category'=>'contact'),
        'contact'   => array('category'=>'contact')
    );
    foreach (preg_split("/\s/", $query) as $word)
    {
        if (isset($keywords[$word]))
        {
            echo $keywords[$word]['category'];
            if ($keywords[$word]['category'] == 'marriage') {
                $marriageNum++;
            }
            echo $marriageNum;
        }
    }
    //return reset($matches);
}
```

I've got a php fiddle setup here:  http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/i4g-mdu that I've been playing around with.  In it's current form, I can get the words into categories but I'm not sure how to count how many times each category gets matched.  I feel like I need an additional loop or something simple to count but I'm not exactly sure where.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`str_word_count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) may help you here! :)

Comment: You might use str_word_count() rather than preg_split(); and array_count_values() might also be a useful function to consider

Comment: Thanks Mark.  When you mentioned array_count_values() that got me thinking about pushing the category name to a new array for each match and then counting each instance but Drawman's solution below seemed easier.  thanks for commenting though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need another array of data, to store the counts. Use an array like this:

```
$counts = array(
    'criminal' => 0,
    'marriage' => 0, 
    'contact' => 0
);
```

Then when you iterate through your foreach loop, you can use the $keywords[$word]['category'] as the key in $counts and increment it:

```
if(isset($keywords[$word]) {
    $counts[$keywords[$word]['category']]++;
}
```

Then you can return the $counts array so the caller can use it to find out what the counts of each theme were:

```
return $counts;
```